# Time indication in a football game

Tags: word-usage

After I have read quite a number of sports news about football match, I notice one interesting thing about the time indication.

It seems to me that when a player does something in the field like scoring a goal or being booked, the time should be a spot, but not a range or a period of time. So the proper expression should have been "Chinese striker Gao Lin scored a penalty on the 84th minute in the game between China and Uzbeckistan", but the news of many agencies is "on the 84 minutes of the game", which looks like a long time. Did the player do this spending a period as long as 84 minutes?

Comment: Give you quote some examples? Are these written by the Chinese press, or by presses who feature native speakers?

Comment: What I would expect is "Chinese striker Gao Lin scored a penalty **at** the 84th minute in the game between China and Uzbeckistan." or *at the 84th minute mark*.  It is *at* that refers to points of time.

Comment: It could also be **in** the 84th minute.

Comment: "In" is definitely most common in reference to this particular sport.